# Rails 3.2 : validates_presence_of inherited model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, model

I have defined three classes:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Cat < Animal
  has_many :toys
end

class Toy
  validates_presence_of :cat
  belongs_to :cat
end
```

When I create a toy that should belong to a cat with :
`Cat.first.toys << Toy.create!(:name => 'Toy 1')`

it throws :

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Cat can't be blank`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cat.first.toys << Toy.create!(:name => 'Toy 1')
```

The sequence of the code would be executed like the following:

```
tmp_toy = Toy.create!(:name => 'Toy 1')
Cat.first.toys << tmp_toy
```

So when you are creating the new toy, you did not provide the required cat, that causes the error.

You could use the following:

```
Cat.first.toys.create!(:name => 'Toy 1')
```